# CMake generate shared library with Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, shared-libraries

I am new to CMake. I want to compile a shared lib of my code with OpenCV lib. Here is my CMakeLists file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(FM)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(HEADER_FILES
        FeatureExtract2.h
        FeatureCompare2.h
        Matching.h
        Helper.h
        )

set(SOURCE_FILES
        FeatureExtract2.cpp
        FeatureCompare2.cpp
        Matching.cpp
        )

add_library(FM SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(FM OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And this is CMake error:

`(target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "FM" which is not built by this project.`

What am I doing wrong here? Much appreciated!

Comment: With misprint fixing `OpenCV_LIBS}` -> `${OpenCV_LIBS}` in the last line this should work. If not, try to use *different names* for the project and the target: some generators do not like that.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks @Tsyvarev